# SSRS Report - 2 Datasets using Lookup but need separate rows in Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, dataset, lookup, ssrs-tablix

My report is written and working for the most part but the question I have is...is there a way to have multiple datasets in a single report that you can connect between and retrieve multiple rows in a single tablix?

Dataset 1 is connected to Dataset 2 through a Lookup and when I run the report, I get the first record from Dataset 2 but Dataset 2 actually has 20 records that it should be displaying.  I know if I do a lookupset and add Environment.NewLine to the end of the lookup, I will get my records on a new line but this is in a Tablix and I need a new row in the tablix.  Is that possible to do?

Using Visual Studio 2017 for my report/project.

Comment: No, there's not a way to split the string from a Lookup into a usuable object for a table. I think your best bet is a subreport with a table with one column to show the rows you need from dataset 2.

Comment: Thanks for the note on this and I was afraid that is what I was going to hear.  I'll have to rework my report based on this now.  Unfortunately, the report is one I am modifying that has a report with multiple subreports and it is being run from an AMS platform directly that doesn't allow subreports within a subreport.